# Semantic UI search return cards?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I'd like to have a Semantic UI `search` component return a list of `cards`, rather than its native interface, something like this:

[image]

At the moment, the `search` returns the results as a list:

[image]

and the cards are rendered on the server:

```
<div class="ui secondary menu">

  <div class="item">
      <div id="contacts" class="ui search">
        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search contacts...">
        <div class="results"></div>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="ui stackable cards">

<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>

  <div class="ui card">
    <div class="content">
      <img class="right floated mini ui image" src="<%= gravatar_url contact[:work_email] %>">
      <div class="header">
        <a href="/contacts/<%= contact[:id] %>"><%= contact[:first_name] %> <%= contact[:last_name] %></a>
      </div>
       <div class="meta">
        <%= contact[:domain] %>
      </div>
    </div><!-- content -->
  </div><!-- /ui card -->

<% end %>
</div>
```

I would like to have the search return the results to a `div`:

```
<div class="ui stackable cards"></div>
```

I think I need to create a template to generate each card, however.

Is this possible?